# Android Studio login with firebase not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app is showing an error at the text fields but Android Studio shows me that all is correct.
Code:

```
package com.vrobinde.reminder;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class LoginPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText loginEmail, loginPassword;
    TextView cAcc;
    Button loginButton;
    FirebaseAuth fireAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loginpage);

        loginEmail      = findViewById(R.id.emailAdressLogin);
        loginPassword   = findViewById(R.id.passwordLogin);
        loginButton     = findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        cAcc            = findViewById(R.id.noAccRegLink);
        fireAuth        = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarlogin);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if(fireAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            String email = loginEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = loginPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    loginEmail.setError("Email Address is required!");
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    loginPassword.setError("Password is required!");
                    return;
                }
                fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, "Login successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, "An error occurred!" + task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        });

        cAcc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterPage.class));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Mistake on my side or Android Studio? I used nearly the same code in my register page and everything is working fine there.

The only difference is, that the String Names in my register class are white and in the login class is purple.

I've no stacktrace in the Debug Console.

Comment: Would you please tell us what kind of error is being shown on text fields?

Comment: The Error message I've set "Email Address is required!" @Bita Mirshafiee

Comment: and are you sure you are filling the TextField with this id 'emailAdressLogin'

Comment: @BitaMirshafiee yes, 100% If I remove return from 'emailAdressLogin' password has also the error I've set before

Comment: ok instead if if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) write if(TextUtils.isEmpty(loginEmail.getText().toString())), I think there is a problem in email assignment

Comment: @BitaMirshafiee thank you, fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put these lines inside the onClick() method instead of putting them directly under setOnClickListener.

```
String email = loginEmail.getText().toString().trim();
String password = loginPassword.getText().toString().trim();
```

It's better if you declare *String email* and *String password* directly under the class (as instance variables).